# How do decrypt Bouncy Castle (AES/CBC) data in PHP?

Tags: java, php, encryption, cryptography, bouncycastle

We have some files that were encrypted using Java Bouncy Castle's "PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC" algorithm.

What is the best library to use in PHP to decrypt these files using PHP?

Comment: use mcrypt in php, but im not sure the details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AES decryption can be done via this:

```
function decrypt($encrypted, $key, $iv) {
    $decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $encrypted, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
    $padSize = ord(substr($decrypted, -1));
    return substr($decrypted, 0, $padSize*-1);
}
```

`$key`, `$iv` and `$encrypted` should be binary strings.

The substr and pad size detection are necessary because `128BITAES-CBC-BC` uses PKCS5 padding which PHP's `mcrypt` functions doesn't support (PHP always pads with zeros).

The harder part is going to be calculating the encryption key. Bouncy Castle's `PBEWITHSHA256` uses PKCS12 with SHA256 to derive the key. The issue here is that I don't know of (and haven't been able to find) any implementation of this algorithm in PHP, and honestly I don't think you'll find one. If all your data is encrypted with a single key, I would recommend debugging the Bouncy Castle library and extracting the key bytes at the start of the encryption/decryption process. You should be able to catch the key if you set a breakpoint in the `generateWorkingKey(byte[], boolean)` method of the `org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.AESFastEngine` class.